# How to set "General->TargetName", "Debugging->Command" and "Linker->General->Output File"

Tags: c, visual-c++, dllexport

I am getting warning in VS project compilation. Though it compile successfully, I  could not get output of my file. Do you have any idea how to set each above?

It is talking about which command and outfile file? What path should be given?

```
//testlib.h

#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void hello();
```

c++ file file is as below :

```
//testlib.cpp

#include "testlib.h"

void hello() {
    printf("DLL hello() called\n");
}
```

and main.cpp is as below:

```
//main.cpp
#include <testlib.h>

int main() {
    hello();
}
```

I am creating dll for testlib.h and testlib.cpp.
Then I want to use it to run main.cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

Use dll for creating project with testlib.h and testlib.cp

use windows project when you create the new project for main.cpp
Executing this creates .exe file.

Add .dll file in same folder as .exe file and it will work as per your need!